# Do I have to pay more than once if I pay my credit card bill and then use it again before the statement due date?

Tags: credit-card, credit, billing

I have paid everything off on my credit card this month but my bill payment says sept 6 can I use my credit card on August 31 and not have to pay again til the bill payment date rolls around or will I have to pay just wanting to know if I will be charged something

Comment: I would really suggest cleaning up your explanation and question so what you're asking is a bit more clear.  That way people can offer better advice when they understand what you're asking.  (smile)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite clear on your question, but I *assume* you're saying you paid off your credit card before the statement due date of September 6th, and you're wondering if you'll have to make another payment by the 6th if you use it now.

As long as your payment happened *after* the end of the billing cycle that the statement for September 6th is for then the answer is, no.  You have already paid the bill for the current billing cycle, so anything you charge now will go on the **next** billing statement.

I often do the same thing.  I pay my statement as soon as it arrives in my inbox, which is weeks ahead of the actual due date.  I don't have to make any further payments until the end of the next billing cycle when the new statement arrives.

I hope this helps.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you asking a different question than Daniel.

Your balance is $3k and you pay in full, but then charge $100 before the bill is cut. When you get the bill for $100, you have to make another payment. Since I always have charges pending, it's tough to actually time it to have a zero balance statement.

Comment: That's what I was trying to convey, so maybe I missed the mark.  If her payment was made after the billing statement issued then any new charges would apply to the next billing cycle, not the current one she has the statement for.  Good point about trying to time it for a zero balance, Joe!

Comment: Hmm. I hope she clarifies the question, because as you said first, it's tough to understand her intent.